# Should i fetch single items in vuex with getters or with actions and SQL statements

Tags: postgresql, express, vue.js, fetch, vuex

Sorry if the question sounds a little bit weird, but i don't know how to explain it the best way.

I'm building a simple fullstack app with Vue, Vuex, Express and Postgresql.

Now I'm fetching data from my database and displaying it on my view. Everything works fine, but I noticed that I could do it in two different ways so I wanted to ask you, what is the best solution.

The First way:

I define two separate routes in my express app. The first returns all customer objects and the second return only a specific customer. Then I can call a action in my vuex to fetch the data and display the data through getters in my template

Express.app:

```
router.route('/')
.get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allcustomer = await db.query(`select * from Kunde`);
        res.json(allcustomer.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json('An error occurred!');
    }
})



router.route('/:id')
.get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const onecustomer = await db.query(`Select * from Kunde where kunde.id = ${id}`)
        console.log(onecustomer.rows[0]);
        res.send(onecustomer.rows[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        res.send("An error occurred!");
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Vuex:

```
const state = {
customers: [],
onecustomer: {}
}

const getters = {
allcustomers: (state) => state.customers,
onecustomer: (state) => state.onecustomer,
}

const actions = {
async fetchcustomers({ commit }) {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/customer');
    commit('setcustomers', response.data);
},

async fetchonecustomer({ commit }, id) {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/customer/${id}`);
    console.log(response.data)
    commit('setonecustomer', response.data);
}
}
```

The second way:

I only have one route in my express app, who return all customers. In my Vuex I only have on actions who fetch all customers from this route and I have one getter method who filters the state array by a id property and through this getter I display my data on my view.

Express app:

```
router.route('/')
.get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const allcustomer = await db.query(`select * from Kunde`);
        res.json(allcustomer.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json('An error occurred!');
    }
})
```

Vuex:

```
const state = {
customers: [],
}

const getters = {
allcustomers: (state) => state.customers,
onecustomer: (state) => (id) => this.state.customers.filter(customer => customer.id = id)
}

const actions = {
async fetchcustomers({ commit }) {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/customer');
    commit('setcustomers', response.data);
},
}

const mutations = {
setcustomers: (state, customers) => (state.customers = customers),
}
```

Both methods are working and I get the same results, but which of these ways are the best one or is it just personally preference?

but I noticed on the second solution I get an error message on my console in my Browser that the object what my getter response is undefined but the data is displayed as I wanted.

I personally would take the first solution because of the error message and its feeling some kind of natural to me.

But what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all read up on sql injection. Your second endpoint is currently **unsafe** and can be used to compromise any and all data in your database.

Besides that, the following line does not do what you think it does:

```
onecustomer: (state) => (id) => this.state.customers.filter(customer => customer.id = id)
```

In this line you assign `id` to `customer.id` for each customer, and return an array. You probably want something like this

```
onecustomer: (state) => (id) => this.state.customers.find(customer => customer.id === id)
```

In general, doing network requests is an expensive operation. You need to send a request, wait for the response, then parse the response. Your second option is better in the sense that you only send the data once. In most cases however you paginate such queries and you might not have the data available when you load a single customer.

If you preload all the data, then having one request to load all customers is all you need. If you do not preload all data, just load a single customer when you do not have the data already. In most cases, you need the two endpoints you have in your first option.